# скопировать в терминале путь к файлу

Tags: linux, файлы, файловая-система, terminal

Наверняка есть способ, работая в терминале, находясь в конкретной папке, как скопировать путь к данному файлу?

**Применимость:** сохраниние пути файла в отдельный файл.

> Как я это вижу:

`$ copy file path > FilesPaths.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте pwd (Print Working Directory):

```
> pwd > filename.txt
```

Нет лучше всего так (Путь и файл, text.txt *обнулится*):

```
> readlink -e filename > text.txt
```

Чуть не забыл, *добавить* запись нужно так:

```
> readlink -e filename >> text.txt
```

Comment: стоит упомянуть`realpath` — `man readlink` рекомендует его для канонизации. Кроме того оба они кроме прочего разрешают симлинки, но у `realpath` есть ключ `-s`, который это отключает... если об этом забыть/не знать, то можно напороться на неожиданные последствия...

Comment: @alexglebe спасибо, как раз то, что доктор прописал.